# Getting a list of member method declarations into a text editor

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Say I want to write a vector-based string (`String`) just for the heck of it and I want an efficient `c_str()` operation on it.

Seems easy enough if I simply ensure the following:

```
//Make sure end() points to a '\0' and that '\0' is in allocated space
void afterEachNonConst() { reserve(size()+1); *(end()) = '\0'; }
```

Then c_str() is "just" `begin()` converted to `const char*`:

```
//Return C-string
const char* c_str() const { return (const char*)(&((*this)[0])); }
```

(I don't know how to do it shorter; the type system seems very unwilling to convert `vector<char>::const_iterator` to `const char*` even though they should be the same).

With that I want to override every non-const non-void method (except for and `reserve`) with:

```
auto ret = vector::method(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...);
//^can't it be just something like `auto ret = super();` ??
afterEachNonConst(); 
return ret;
```

and every non-const void method with:

```
 vector::method(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...);
 afterEachNonConst();
```

*I guess there's no reasonably elegant way to just let C++ metaprogramming do all the work (?). Can I at least get a **listing** of all vector method signatures into my text editor somehow?*

---

Here's a compilable example I played with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>

class String : public std::vector<char> {
  public:

  //Initialize from c-string
  String& operator=(const char* cstr) {
    size_t length = strlen(cstr);
    reserve(strlen(cstr) + 1);
    resize(length);
    for(iterator ptr = begin(); *ptr++=*cstr++; ); //this will copy the '\0' too, but only at end()
    return *this;
  }
  String(const char* cstr){ (*this) = cstr; }

  //Return C-string
  const char* c_str() const { return (const char*)(&((*this)[0])); }

  void push_back(char value){
    vector::push_back(value);
    afterEachNonConst();
  };

  private:
  //Make sure end() points to a '\0' and that '\0' is in allocated space
  void afterEachNonConst() { reserve(size()+1); *(end()) = '\0'; }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  using namespace std;
  String a = "foobar";
  assert(a.size() == strlen(a.c_str()));
  a.push_back('_');
  a.push_back('1');
  assert(a.size() == strlen(a.c_str()));
  cout<<a.c_str()<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your _text editor_ actually? Your question seems a bit confused.

Comment: Vim, but really it's about getting a listing that I can process.

Comment: Look up the C++ standard or the file <vector> of your implementation. It's tedious, though, and makes little sense. Just use `std::string`, man (there are better things for you to do than reinventing this wheel).

Comment: @Walter it's not about the actual example problem of reimplementing string. It's about learning and getting software to look up the information I need from the headers.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do cannot be done with metaprogramming. You'd need reflection as part of the language, which is IMHO sadly a missing feature of C++.

To get a list of the member functions of `std::vector` I'd go and open the standard, N4431 §23.3.6 and try to extract them from there.

If this is too "much work" you could also try to implement something using libclang or libTooling, though this seems by far easier as it really is. (I just had to do something similar)

Since the syntax of C++ is so extremely complicated, especially in combination with templates, parsing it is really hard. Sadly using the above libraries it's also very hard to reproduce a parsed member function declaration.

Comment: Just found out that Eclipse autocompletion does give you a nice method listing -- full signatures except for the const qualifiers. I'm wondering if I can extract that and possible have it list the qualifiers too.